# Use XERO API in CRM Plugin, RSA Encryption Private Key Issues(CRM ONLINE)

Tags: c#, rsa, dynamics-crm-2013, x509certificate2

I am trying to connect MS CRM 2015 plugin(online) with XERO Accounting system(online).

XERO has an api with source code available. We have downloaded the source code and are using the same in our plugin code.

Unfortunately XERO uses RSA public/private key encryption for authentication etc.
In plugin we do not have access to key store thus private key becomes unavailable, I have tried to export the key from a console app and embed the file as resource in plugin. It failed giving me this error

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

I hope I am making some sense, if anybody else has faced and solved this problem, please let me know how you did it.

Comment: Show your code. The inaccessibility of the key in the keystore is, most likely, either due to permissions or wrong user account under which the key is installed. Double-check your configuration.

Comment: I have access to the public key and private key as xml file.
But CRM online plugin does not give me access to the key store.
If I try to read this xml file(resource) in the plugin to initialize the certificate or the key, it throws this error

Comment: Have you done a trace to find the root cause line of code throwing this error? There is a line of code executing which prohibited by security permissions granted to the AppDomain executing the plugin in CRM Online.

Comment: I had the same issue and the I traced it to the point which was raising the exception. It was signingCertificate.PrivateKey i.e. the moment the code tries to access the PrivateKey it threw the error. Had even raised a ticket with Microsoft but they told me that it was not possible to access PrivateKey in online environment. Were you able to solve it? Regards,
- NikSon

Comment: @Sudeep Were you able to resolve this issue? if yes then how? what was your solution to this problem?